# How to use Homomorphic Encryption in tensorflow-federated

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am using tensorflow-federated(TFF) to develop my own federated aggregation method. I wonder if I can use Homomorphic Encryption(HE) in tensorflow-federated. I notice that TFF uses tff.federated_mean() to aggregate the gradients from every clients. Does TFF provide a similar API or interface to implement HE? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

TFF can be conceptualized as having several components, two of which are the core primitives of a domain-specific language for federated learning (this is what you get when you write `tff.federated_mean`), and a runtime to execute programs expressed in this language (this is what you get when you pass some python values into your TFF-decorated function).

At the DSL level, TFF indeed has support for at least some homomorphic encryption; in particular, check out [`tff.federated_secure_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_secure_sum) and the recent addition of [`tff.federated_secure_select`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_secure_select).

You can use these in the bodies of your TFF functions, but they *will not execute in TFF's default runtime*. TFF's default runtime is often run entirely in a single datacenter, with the notions of clients and server not necessarily mapping directly to machines. See for example [this code](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/core/impl/executors/federated_resolving_strategy.py#L530) where the TFF default runtime would raise when trying to execute these primitives.

However, TFF's runtime design is fundamentally component-driven and compositional, and these primitives can be implemented in a way that composes into the rest of TFF's native runtime. See [this blog post](https://medium.com/dropoutlabs/building-secure-aggregation-into-tensorflow-federated-4514fca40cc0) by Dropout Labs for a description of how they built support for `secure_sum` on top of TFF--indeed, it was their collaboration with TFF that resulted in some of the patterns in the linked code above. Their implementation of support for `secure_sum` [remains on GitHub](https://github.com/tf-encrypted/federated-aggregations/blob/master/federated_aggregations/paillier/factory.py#L109), though I suspect that there is no support for `secure_select` yet, as it was quite recently added to TFF.